# Las subsecciones del sitio no aparecen resaltadas

Tags: bug, estado-completado, diseño

Al parecer hay un bug que no permite que las subsecciones de la página resalten, o en su defecto algo anda mal con mi navegador XD

Por ejemplo la subsección de *recientes* no está resaltada

> [image]

Comment: A mí me pasa lo mismo. <strike>Es</strike> **Era** mas notable en [webapps.se] que tiene un fondo de color gris en lugar de blanco. Ahora el resaltado se muestra sólo al pasar el puntero sobre recientes, destacadas, etc.

Comment: Ah bueno entonces supongo que es un cambio de estilos? sin embargo en el sitio en inglés el nuevo diseño de la web si resalta las subsecciones

Comment: Ojala que solo sea un bug de transicion al nuevo diseño :D

Comment: Dentro de poco imagino que recibamos el nuevo UI de StackExchange, así que se solucionará el problema

Comment: Ya vuelve a verse la pestaña seleccionada

Comment: Sip, ya se arregló